# How to hide or block the WooCommerce generated pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When activating WooCommerce, the plugin generates a few pages responsible for outputting the store functionality. This is all good, except I had a few occasions where the client or someone in his behalf deletes this pages. They look like empty pages anyway.

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening, maybe by hiding them from the customer (shop manager role) or block them to further editions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that will automatically collect the IDs of the pages generated by Woocommerce. The plugin upon installation creates four pages ( Shop, Cart, Checkout, My Account ), and saves the IDs of that pages in the database inside `wp_options` table. Option names are:

- `woocommerce_shop_page_id`
- `woocommerce_cart_page_id`
- `woocommerce_checkout_page_id`
- `woocommerce_myaccount_page_id`

The example collects the IDs automatically within [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action ( that runs before the actual query is executed ), if the current user is not an `administrator` WC generated pages will not be to retrieved.

The second part is for disabling the `edit page` link in the `admin bar`. Because the logged in user still has direct access to pages through the admin bar, [`wp_before_admin_bar_render`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render) action is used to remove `edit page` link, of course only for WC pages, same as in the first part.

Put this in `functions.php`, or create a plugin if you want theme independent solution.

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() ) return;

    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page' && !in_array( 'administrator', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {

        $exclude = array_map( 
            function( $item ) { return get_option( $item ); }, 
            array( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id', 'woocommerce_cart_page_id', 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id', 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' )
        );

        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array_filter( $exclude ) );

    }

});



add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', function() {
    if ( is_admin() || !is_page() ) return;

    global $wp_admin_bar;   

    $exclude = array_map( 
        function( $item ) { return get_option( $item ); }, 
        array( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id', 'woocommerce_cart_page_id', 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id', 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' )
    );

    if ( in_array( get_queried_object()->ID, $exclude ) && !in_array( 'administrator', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) )
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu( 'edit' );

});
```

Here are some links that have helped me:
http://www.johnparris.com/how-to-hide-pages-in-the-wordpress-admin/
http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/exclude-pages-from-admin-edit-pages-list/

Comment: One could add `woocommerce_refund_returns_page_id` to that list nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to the functions.php file will hide pages from everyone except admins.

```
function exclude_pages_from_admin($query) {
    if($query->is_admin) {

        $caps = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'wp_capabilities', true);
        $roles = array_keys((array)$caps);
        if( ! in_array('administrator', $roles) ){
            $ids = array('53'); // Enter Page ids to restrict here
            $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = $ids;

            if( in_array(get_the_ID(), $ids) ) {
                wp_redirect(admin_url());
            }
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'exclude_pages_from_admin',99);
```

This will still show the "Edit Page" option while on the page, but trying to edit it will cause the users to be redirected to the dashboard.

The above was found [here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/i-need-a-plugin-that-will-restrict-page-edit-access-but) and slightly modified, it has been tested and should work

Comment: Much appreciated your help Howlin, for some reason that doesn't seem to hide the pages, after passing the page IDs and switch to an user with less than Administrator capabilities. 
I guess i'll have to run a few more tests, I'll post it here if I come to any conclusion.

Comment: Just tested with the version from the original blog posted you've mentioned and with that version it works. Not sure what is going wrong with your version.

Comment: Hmm the only difference is that they used editor and page id 5 and I used administrator and page id 53